# assort merge two assorted arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge two assorted arrays assorting the result as well in PHP this is the code that I have managed to come up with:

```
<?php
function assotAssortedArrays($a, $b){
  if (empty($a)){
    return $b;
  }
  if (empty($b)){
    return $a;
  }
  if ($a[0] < $b[0]){
    return array_merge($a[0],  
            array_merge(array_slice($a, 1, count($a)-1), $b));
  } else {
    return array_merge($b[0], 
            array_merge(array_slice($b, 1, count($b)-1), $a));        
  }
}

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(3,4,5,6,7);
var_dump(assotAssortedArrays($a, $b));
```

The code does not work, this is the error that I am getting:

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in D:\Web\a\sortArrays.php on line 14
```

Basically the interpreter is saying that argument 1 here `array_merge(array_slice($b, 1, count($b)-1), $a));` is not and array, but I have done print_r on all elements and it says they are arrays. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**, Thanks to Sam This is the correct code:

```
function mergeArrays($a, $b){
    if (empty($a)){
        return $b;
    }
    if (empty($b)){
        return $a;
    }
    if ($a[0] < $b[0]){
        $aux[] = $a[0];
        return array_merge($aux, mergeArrays(array_slice($a, 1, count($a)), $b));
    } else {
        $aux[] = $b[0];
        return array_merge($aux, mergeArrays(array_slice($b, 1, count($b)), $a));        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the slice is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message might be misleading, the actual problem is with the call to `array_merge` before your `array_merge(array_slice(...`.

The values of `$a[0]` and `$b[0]` are not arrays.

Comment: Thank you, it was what you were saying. Now I have other problems, but that problem is solved.